# Display div content only once in hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is possible to show div in header of page to visitor only once in hour?

I want to show a bar which shows to a visitor whether we're open or closed. The 'visitor A' should see it at every first page he loads and on the next page not. In 30 minutes it should be shown to him again.

I'm running jquery 1.10.2 at my website.

Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies, set a cookie that lasts for an hour, and then with your code make some checks :

- If the cookie does **not** exist, then display the `div`, create the cookie and make it last an hour
- If the cooie **does** exist, then do nothing

I don't think that you can handle cookies with jQuery directly, there are some plugins out there though. Or, you can use a server side programming langage such as PHP.

It depends on what it is you want to show though. If it's just an ad or a reminder (ex: take a look at our xmas promotion) then you could simply display it at every hour. In your jQuery script, check the time, and if it's a "round" hour (not sure how to say this) such as 7:00, 8:00 or something, show the `div`, and then hide it after a minute or whatever.

#### Example with PHP

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['yourCookie']))
    {
        //Set the cookie
        setcookie("yourCookie", "open", time() + 3600); //Expires in an hour            
        echo '<div class="open">We are open!</div>';            
    }
?>
```

When you will reload the page, the cookie will exist, so the `div` will not be shown. After an hour the cookie will be deleted, so the next time the user refreshes the page it will be shown, and the cookie will be set again.

The downside of a server-side solution is that unless the user refreshes the page after an hour, it won't be shown after exactly an hour like with Javascript.

**Edit** You have to set the cookie **before** outputting any HTML, otherwise it will fail! Make sure that the instruction to set the cookie is before any HTML in your code.

Comment: I want to show a bar which shows to a visitor whether we're open or closed. The visitor A should see it at every first page he loads and on the next page not. In 30 minutes it should be shown to the visitor A again. I guess it's cookie's work but I don't know much about it. Do you have sample please?

Comment: Seems like cookies are appropriate, are you able to use a server-side language like PHP - I can make you an example - or do you have to use only javascript/jQuery?

Comment: That would be lovely. I don't mind php. I'll take solution which is simplier :)

Comment: I edited my post to include a piece of code! The `echo` of the `div` can be replaced by something else (ex: adding a class or something), I just did this as an example.

Comment: Thank you, that very simple why I didn't finded at internet? :) The downside of server-side solution is fine to me. And just tell me please. Does it slow down page load time more then javascript solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'd have to do some tests on your own, but I would think that a cookie that stores a simple value and four lines of code won't slow down your website too much (especially if you compare to the amount of code required to have a similar behaviour with JS).

Comment: That's what I though as well :) Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your div has `id="specialContent"`, something like this (after document load, in your `$(document).ready(function() { ... } );` or wherever) should do the trick...

```
function showSpecialContent() {
    $('#specialContent').show();
    setTimeout(hideSpecialContent, 1000*30); // show the content for 30 seconds, then hide it
    document.cookie = "lastshown=" + Date.now();
}

function hideSpecialContent() {
   $('#specialContent').hide();
   setTimeout(showSpecialContent, 1000*60*60); // hide the content, and then show it again in an hour
}

function initTimers() { 
    var lastShown = getCookie("lastshown");
    if(lastShown) {
        var lsd = new Date(new Number(lastShown));

        var timeShownDelta = Date.now() - lsd;
        // if we last showed the div more than an hour ago
        if (timeShownDelta > 60*60*1000) {   
            showSpecialContent();
        } else {
            setTimeout(showSpecialContent, 1000*60*60 - timeShownDelta); 
        }

    } else {
        showSpecialContent();
    }
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

initTimers();
```

and an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vj2dqqyr/4/

Comment: I have tried your but it didn't work nor at my website nor at jsfiddle.net.. The div didn't disappear in 30 seconds and next load it was shown again.

Comment: @sidlo check out http://jsfiddle.net/vj2dqqyr/
The div appears as soon as the code executes, disappears after 5 seconds, and then reappears 5 seconds later.

Comment: You may also want to check out setInterval, which unlike setTimeout will execute every x milliseconds.  setTimeout will only execute once after the timeout.

Comment: @sidlo, ahah, you also want persistence of that hour across page loads. cookies!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. Do you have any sample of code?

Comment: @sidlo check my update to answer + fiddle

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found simpler to use php solution. But I guess I'll use it in future at static page without php option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fns6e7yc/1/

```
<div id='showOnceAnHour' style='display: none'>
    Something to show  
</div>
```

In your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#showOnceAnHour").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
    }, 60*60*1000);
});
```

Comment: Using setInterval with non-blocking code isn't usually a good idea. In your example, because the delay < interval, it's okay; but async + setInterval = terrifying